# Not getting correct result in RHadoop MAP function

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, rhadoop

Below is my text file content:

```
name ,      tag/tags ,               location,           id
xyz,         abc;nhj;xygf;xyz;ajsd,  jhdwegyugagdwg,     T1
xasdiaos,    abcd,                   jhdwegyugagdwg0 ,   T3
xyzasihd,   jsdh;sdgwyi,             jhdwegyugagdasodpg, T2
xyzasihd,    jsdh;jadh;ahsg;sdgwyi,  jhdwegyugagdasodpg, T4
```

I want to output the id's  and total number of tags.
Desired output is as follows.

```
T1 , 5
T3 , 1
T2 , 2
T4 , 4
```

I have written below piece of code for `mapreduce`.

```
library(rmr2)

query1= function(input, output = "/user/mtech/15CS60R13/OutputP2"){

  q1.map=
    function(., lines){
      print(lines)

      keyval(unlist(strsplit(lines,split=","))[4],
             length(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(lines,split=","))[2],split=";"))))
    }

  mapreduce(
    input = input ,
    output = output,
    input.format = "text",
    map = q1.map,
  )
}

query1("/user/xyz/file.txt")

results <- from.dfs ("/user/mtech/15CS60R13/Output")
```

I am getting results as follows.

```
print(results)
$key
[1] "T4" "T1"

$val
[1] 4 5
```

Although when I tried below change in `map` function,

```
keyval(lines,1)
```

I am getting all the 4 lines. Please explain why I am getting only 2 lines when I am putting `strsplit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the mistake in map:

```
q1.map=
function(., lines){
 for(line in lines){
  keyval(unlist(strsplit(line,split=","))[4],
         length(unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(line,split=","))[2],split=";"))))
}
}
```

Thank You !